# Men in thongs on mediterranean beaches?

Tags: legal, local-customs, beaches, swimming, mediterranean

So I am travelling in a few weeks to Barcelona, Cote D'azur, and to Genoa Italia and was wondering if men wear thongs on these beaches. I want to try it personally but am unsure how taboo it would be. Otherwise I will wear my speedo. I'm 22, good body, and want to just tan in a thong swimsuit.

Comment: Women can wear thongs on mediterranean beaches. Why wouldn't men be allowed to do so?

Comment: You mean something like this: http://img.thesun.co.uk/aidemitlum/archive/02358/01_28094726_9dc503_2358295a.jpg ?

Comment: @JoErNanO I don't think it's hard to come up with examples of clothing that are socially acceptable for one gender to wear and not the other.

Comment: Since you own a substitute bathing suit, and a thong won't exactly take up space in your suitcase, why not bring both? Head to the beach in your Speedo and if it looks like thongs are pretty common and not worthy of comment or remark, change into yours. You don't really need to know in advance - just bring both!

Comment: I would search for photos in Google for that beach, check the photos and see...

Comment: For your visit to Barcelona at least, you might want to take a look at the beaches of Sitges, a small town 40km to the south (but easily accessible by train). http://barcelona-home.com/blog/the-beaches-of-sitges/ suggests that there are a few nudist beaches, gay straight and mixed, but that at all of them clothing is also ok.

Comment: Bearing in mind that this is an international site and that "thongs" means very different things in different dialects of English, this question would benefit greatly from an image. (E.g. I assume from context that you're not Australian and talking about footwear, but...)

Answer (score 7):

To be legally covered (pun intended), just make sure that you have some piece of clothing around your scrotum and the shaft.

The social aspect is quite more complex and the acceptable degree of skimpiness will not just differ between cities, but also between the different beaches in each region. Even if male thongs are not too common on mediterranean beaches, except on strict nude beaches, where even a thong may be too much, I would doubt that anyone at all would bother if an odd guest is wearing one.

Comment: Having lived all my life at most at 30 minutes from a beach, and more or less half the beaches around my region being nudist, I've never seen a male thong here. If you want nice tan, you just go to a nudist beach and wear nothing.